# Html Encoded Code Expressions

Tags: asp.net, syntax, asp.net-4.0

In ASP.NET 4.0

should I use new syntax `<%: expression %>` or 2.0 `<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(expression) %>`

Comment: I have a feeling you made this question just to create the asp.net-4 tag....

Comment: @John, I think that tag has existed for awhile, its just always renamed to 4.0 to be consistent with 2.0 and 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less keystrokes, less chance to make a mistake, easier to read => use the first option.

Answer (score 0):

That's sort of like asking if you should do this:

```
<%= DateTime.Now %>
```

or this

```
<% Response.Write(DateTime.Now) %>
```

There's no right answer, but one certainly looks better to me.